# two element ticks in a parametricplot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I'm struggling with parametric plot axes ticks edition. I need them to always have one (or two) digits after the coma but now they are like: 0,6 0,8 1, 1,2 1,4 and I need the to be like: 0,6 0,8 1,0 1,2 1,4... Please help!

Example of the code:

```
f[x_] := x
g[x_] := x

ticksX = Table[x, {x, 0, 4, 0.2}];
ticksY = Table[x, {x, 0, 4, 0.1}];
grids = {Table[x, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}], Table[x, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}]};

Style[ParametricPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Black}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["n", FontSize -> 12.5, Italic, 
     FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    Style["m", FontSize -> 12.5, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  GridLines -> grids, Ticks -> {ticksX, ticksY}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12.5, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Directive[Thickness[0.001]]}, {Gray, 
     Directive[Thickness[0.001]]}}, 
  AxesStyle -> {{Black, Directive[Thickness[0.002]]}, {Black, 
     Directive[Thickness[0.002]]}}], NumberPoint -> ","]
```

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 3):

something like this?  See help for more details on these number formatting functions.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ticksX = Table[{x, 
    Rotate[Style[NumberForm[x, {2, 1}, NumberPoint -> ","], Red], 
     90 Degree]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.2}];
ticksY = Table[{x, Style[NumberForm[x, {2, 1}, NumberPoint -> ","], Red]}, {x,
     0, 4, 0.1}];

grids = {Table[x, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}], Table[x, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}]};

Framed@ParametricPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 3},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003], Black}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["n", FontSize -> 12.5, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"],
    Style["m", FontSize -> 12.5, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"]},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  PlotRange -> All,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  GridLines -> grids,
  Ticks -> {ticksX, ticksY},
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 12.5, FontFamily -> "Times"],
  GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Directive[Thickness[0.001]]}, {Gray, 
     Directive[Thickness[0.001]]}},
  AxesStyle -> {{Black, Directive[Thickness[0.002]]}, {Black, 
     Directive[Thickness[0.002]]}},
  ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was wondering how to do. Thank You very much.